# Bypass asp.net output cache for POSTS

Tags: asp.net, outputcache

I am trying to force no caching for POST requests using this implementation:

```
public override string GetVaryByCustomString(HttpContext context, string custom)
{
    if (custom == "RawUrl")
    {
        if (context.Request.HttpMethod.ToUpper() == "POST")
        {
            context.Response.Cache.SetNoServerCaching();
        }
        return context.Request.RawUrl.ToLower();

    }
    return base.GetVaryByCustomString(context, custom);
}
```

But the contents of the control are still returned from the output cache (page load is never called)